# Select all from table where value=multiple values from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to select posts that are posted by somebody the user is following.

My posts table looks like this:

[image: posts structure]

My followers table looks like this:

[image: followers structure]

The "creator" column in the posts table is the ID of the user who posted it. The "follower" colum in the followers table is the user who is following the "following" column.

I'm using this query (to no avail) to select all from posts where creator=all users the user is following:

> SELECT * FROM posts WHERE creator=(SELECT following FROM followers
>   WHERE follower=**the user's id**) ORDER BY datetime DESC;

In theory:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE creator=1 or 2 or 3 or 4...or 998 or 999
```

etc, etc.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: change `creator=` to `creator IN` or do a join

Comment: Use `WHERE creator IN (your subselect)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using joins in this case can boost up the performance of your query. I recommend the following:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p
INNER JOIN followers f 
ON p.creator = f.following
WHERE f.follower = <user_id>
ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Comment: That also works perfectly. Is this faster in any way than Vickrant's answer?

Comment: It'll be if your user is following thousands of posts. Joins are always faster than `IN` in case of huge datasets. Otherwise, performance gain will be minimum and can be ignored.

Comment: Great, thank you for that. I'll keep it in mind! I have to wait  five minute to accept the answer, but then I will.

Comment: Right @RohitAggarwal joins are always faster then in. Great

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE creator in (SELECT following FROM followers WHERE follower=the user's id) ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Comment: Great idea, but it returned no results. **Probably because my user isnt following anybody. Hold on!**

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! I can accept an answer in 8 minutes so I'll have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts p, followers f 
WHERE 
  p.creator=f.following
  and f.follower ='user_id' 
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC;
```